# Using Mockito to spy a method with object argument results in NullPointerException

Tags: scala, nullpointerexception, mockito, scalatest

I am trying to test some code using `Mockito.spy` to provide behavior to some of the functions I need to provide. Although I understand that there may be better alternatives to what I am doing, I am curious why the following code throws a `NullPointerException` in Scala and how could it be solved.

The class `Foo` is being tested. It contains a single method `act`, which for the purpose of this question just calculate the sum of numbers. Class `FooSpec` is the respective unit test for class `Foo`. Class `Bar` is another class that is used as an argument to class `Foo` to demonstrate the case that the exception arises.

The following code **works**. Method `Foo.act` takes in no arguments.

```scala
package foo

import org.mockito.Matchers.any
import org.mockito.Mockito.{spy, times, verify, when}
import org.scalatest.WordSpec
import org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar

class Foo {
  def act(): Int = {
    (1 to 10).sum
  }
}

class FooSpec extends WordSpec with MockitoSugar {
  "a test" in {
    val spiedFoo = spy(new Foo)
    when(spiedFoo.act()).thenReturn(100)

    val result = spiedFoo.act()

    assert(result == 100)
    verify(spiedFoo, times(1)).act()
  }
}
```

The following code **breaks**. Method `Foo.act` takes in 1 argument of type `Bar`. It throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException` for some reason

```scala
package foo

import org.mockito.Matchers.any
import org.mockito.Mockito.{spy, times, verify, when}
import org.scalatest.WordSpec
import org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar

case class Bar(value: Int)

class Foo {
  def act(bar: Bar): Int = {
    (1 to bar.value).sum
  }
}

class FooSpec extends WordSpec with MockitoSugar {
  "a test" in {
    val spiedFoo = spy(new Foo)
    when(spiedFoo.act(any[Bar])).thenReturn(100)

    val aBar = Bar(10)
    val result = spiedFoo.act(aBar)

    assert(result == 100)
    verify(spiedFoo, times(1)).act(any[Bar])
  }
}
```

Here is the error message obtained from the test:

```
[info] FooSpec:
[info] - a test *** FAILED ***
[info]   java.lang.NullPointerException:
[info]   at foo.Foo.act(FooSpec.scala:12)
[info]   at foo.FooSpec$$anonfun$1.apply$mcI$sp(FooSpec.scala:19)
[info]   at foo.FooSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(FooSpec.scala:17)
[info]   at foo.FooSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(FooSpec.scala:17)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
[info]   at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1078)
[info]   at org.scalatest.TestSuite$class.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)
[info]   ...
[info] Run completed in 761 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 1, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] *** 1 TEST FAILED ***
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         foo.FooSpec
[error] (foo/test:testOnly) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed Oct 15, 2019 5:50:20 PM
```

Comment: I have saw similar behavior when involving mocks that deal with value classes, please check if that's the case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Important gotcha on spying real objects](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.1.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) states

> Sometimes it's impossible or impractical to use `when(Object)` for
>   stubbing spies. Therefore when using spies please consider
>   `doReturn|Answer|Throw()` family of methods for stubbing.

Hence try

```
doReturn(100).when(spiedFoo).act(any[Bar])
```

instead of

```
when(spiedFoo.act(any[Bar])).thenReturn(100)
```

Also consider moving to [mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala#idiomatic-mockito), for example

```
class FooSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers with IdiomaticMockito with ArgumentMatchersSugar {
  "a test" in {
    val spiedFoo = spy(new Foo)
    100 willBe returned by spiedFoo.act(*)

    val aBar = Bar(10)
    val result = spiedFoo.act(aBar)

    result shouldEqual  100
    spiedFoo.act(*) was called
  }
}
```